# Tiff image height fft

Tags: image-processing, image, image3d, fourier-analysis

I wanted to import .tiff image to Mathematica and then plot fft of z values (height) of the image i. e. values which are translated to color in the image.
I know that total time to create picture was 200000 seconds.
Every point was created in 10 seconds.

The idea is to see that there is 60 Hz noise in the data.

How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you been able to import your TIFF file (see `Import`)? To extract numerical data from it (see perhaps `ImageData`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data=ImageData[ColorConvert[Import["bild.tiff"],"Grayscale"];
linemean=Plus@@@data;
FT=Fourier[lineman];
```

One has to take account of the fact, that the image data list has ordering bottom to top while images are sorted top row first for sequential output. Reverse can be used to adapt the order.